# Merging tags to values separated by new line character in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database field with several values separated by newline.

Eg-(can be more than 3 also)

```
A
B
C
```

I want to perform an operation to modify these values by adding tags from front and end.

i.e the previous 3 values should need to be turned into

```
<Test>A</Test>
<Test>B</Test>
<Test>C</Test>
```

Is there any possible query operation in Oracle SQL to perform such an operation?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the start and end of each string with the XML tags using a multi-line match parameter of the regular expression:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '^', '<Test>', 1, 0, 'm' ),
         '$', '</Test>', 1, 0, 'm'
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'A
B
C' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | REPLACED_VALUE |
> | :------------- |
> | <Test>A</Test> |
> | <Test>B</Test> |
> | <Test>C</Test> |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d7d92b2fe2e0cb5f39f8bb8969571173)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use normal `replace` function as follows:

```
Select '<test>'
       || replace(your_column,chr(10),'</test>'||chr(10)||'<test>') 
       || '</test>'
From your_table;
```

It will be faster than its `regexp_replace` function.

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=322cb5bea5aeed395555ec8e2d053089)